# Django: How to pass a parameter from template to view

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I have a question: I want to click on an item on the template page and pass the corresponding key to the views.py, how can I do it? Thank you very much. A partial code from template is below:

```
    {% for key,value in wordList.items %}

        <li><a href="{% url 'infoRetriever:sitelist' %}" data-weight={{ value }} >{{ key }}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}
```

Addition:

For example, now I am at the url www.example.com/results.html. On the page there is a list of keys: key1, key2, key3... When I click on a link 'key1', the page would be directed to www.example.com/sitelist/key1
How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: you can make an ajax request from your rendered template to a view

Comment: You either need to have the clicked item be a link to a page (and pass a parameter through a regular expression in the URL), or you need to use something like JavaScript to do a Client Side operation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't pass directly from a template to a view, although you can pass from a view to a template. What you'll need to do is either use AJAX and write another view that handles the GET or POST request and returns some data, or use a link that sends someone to a new page entirely.

Edit:

With the addition, just modify your link in the template. So:

```
   {% for key,value in wordList.items %}
       <li><a href="/sitelist/{{ key }}" data-weight={{ value }}{{ key }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
```

Since using {{ key }} just dumps the text of the variable in place, this will dynamically create your links.

Comment: Thanks, I have an update on the question, could you have a look at it?

Comment: Better yet is to loose the `{{ key }}` and instead use `{% url 'infoRetriever:sitelist' key %}`, as your url needs to catch the key parameter anyway for this to work and is thus reversable this way. You should try to never hard-code your url's into your template.